# Need chargeable momentary 15 watt regulated voltage source

Tags: power-supply, batteries, capacitor, voltage-regulator, charge

I'm working on a RF telemetry side-project that requires an amplifier IC to be run for about 5 seconds bursts between charges. The system is portable and runs off of a 3.3V battery that can supply about 100 mA. The IC runs at 10V and draws 1.5 Amps, so 15 Watts. I can't simply use a boost converter on the device's battery because it can't supply nearly that much power. So I need to store the necessary charge and then dispense it at a regulated voltage.

The output voltage of my charge storage system should be well regulated at 10 volts, and I need it to be able to supply a constant 1.5 Amps for at least 5 seconds, after which I will turn it off and recharge it.

The goals here are to minimize size and amount of time it takes to charge the thing. I assume the solution is either going to be some sort of battery or capacitor with some circuitry to regulate the voltage output.

I don't know very much about practical charge storage and power regulation, but if someone knows a good general approach I can look into the details.

**edit:** Assuming money is no object, anyone interested in elaborating on using a super-cap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

15 W \$\times\$ 5 s = 75 J.  If you want to store that in a capacitor you'll need a capacitance of

\$ C = \dfrac{2 \times 75 J}{(10 V)^2} = 1.5 F \$

There are supercaps with even higher capacitances, but types which can supply a 1.5 A current are between expensive and Damn Expensive™.

A battery will be a better choice. For instance a LiPo followed by a **boost converter**, to have a nicely regulated 10 V, even at varying battery voltage. Use another boost converter to charge the battery between load bursts; I would shut-down the charger while you're transmitting.

If the 3.3 V can supply 100 mA that's 330 mW. Suppose the two boost converters have an efficiency of 85 % then to get the required 75 J output you'll need 105 J input. At 330 mW that will take 315 seconds, that's 5 minutes and 15 seconds. So you can transmit a 5 second burst once every 5 minutes and 20 seconds. If you need a higher frequency you'll have to find another power source.

**edit**
I almost forgot: the battery has a less than 100 % efficiency too. You can't get every joule you put into it out again. So in practice the charging time will have to be longer than the 5 minutes.

I would use two LiPo cells in series. Then you'll have 7.4 V nominal, 8.4 V fully charged. That's relevant, because the closer the voltage to the 10 V the less current will be required from the battery. If you draw 1.5 A at 10 V a 3.7 V cell would have to supply 4.8 A if we take again the 85 % for the booster. Two cells in series will only have to supply 2.4 A.

**edit 2**
Dave's ultracap seems to be a good alternative, but he should mention that the 3.3 V to 2.5 V regulator also has to be a switching regulator, unless you're satisfied with a 75 % efficiency there. If we use eBay as a price reference you can buy a set of two 240 mAh LiPo's for 4.5 dollar, free shipping. That means they only will be discharged for 1 % during the 5 s burst. So while 14 dollar for the cap isn't bad, and definitely something to remember, the LiPo's are only a third of that.

It's also worth noting that stepping down from 3.3 V to 2.5 V and then up to 10 V is less efficient than up from 3.3 V to 7.4 V, and then to 10 V. That's because a switcher's efficiency is related to both the in-out voltage difference and their ratio.

Comment: Fantastic. I figured a capacitor wouldn't work out, haha. I will look more into charging and utilizing LiPo batteries. I've used boost converters before. Thanks!

Comment: @Jay - Thanks for the accept, but don't be too hasty with that. See my edit :-).

Comment: Does drawing less current from the battery just increase the lifespan, or what?

Comment: Err, also I'm a bit confused. Is the battery supposed to entirely discharge in the 5 seconds? That doesn't sound possible/safe.

Comment: @JayKeegan It can be done with caps, but you have to have the willingness to foot the bill for the caps. And no, discharging an entire LiPo battery in 3 seconds is not safe, but if you only need 1.5A at a time then a normal cellphone style battery will last an hour. Making a battery last a long time is very very complex compared to the problem here.

Comment: @Jay - Twice the current is 4 times the power loss in the battery's internal resistance and the circuit's wiring. Bad efficiency-wise. And yes, the higher power loss will increase the battery's temperature, which decreases its lifetime. In practice that may be negligible, since they're designed for high current in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Not a supercap, but an ultracap, which *is* designed for high currents, might work.

Rough calculation: Ultracaps have voltage ratings on the order of 2.5V, so your 1.5A @ 10V translates (ignoring efficiency issues for the moment) into 6A @ 2.5V. 6A for 5 seconds is a charge of 30C. Let's say you can tolerate a voltage drop of 0.1V over the 5s, so the capacitor you would need would be 300F.

To charge this capacitor, you just need a 2.5V regulator driven from your 3.3V supply that's current-limited to 100 mA. To drive your amplifier, you need a boost converter (regulator) that converts the 2.4-2.5V from the capacitor to 10V @ 1.5A. You would enable the boost converter only when you need it, along with the amplifier itself.

Restoring the 30C @ 100 mA (using a linear regulator) would require 300 seconds of dead time between transmissions. Longer, once you take real-world efficiency numbers into account. But if you use a 3.3V-to-2.5V switching regulator, which should give you almost 130 mA out, reduces the nominal recharge time to 227 seconds.

I just checked Ebay, and you can get a single Maxwell 350 Farad Ultracapacitor, which is about the size of a D cell, for about $14.